# Digit relations in numbers

Tags: number-theory

It's quite hard to find a correct tag for this thread since I'm not even sure if what I'm going to ask exists in mathematics at the moment. That's what this question is all about after all. So is there a mathematical way to express the relation of digits in a number? For example $12, 24, 36, 1224$ all have in common this: Their second half is double their first half. $2 = 1 \times2 , 24 = 2 \times12...$ So I would I like to see if there is a way to express this relation using mathematical symbols. Like $[a|2a]$ (It's just an example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We typically use overline to denote concatenation, but you should still explicitly state that it is the case: $\overline{(a)(2a)}$.

For a "closed form", you have $10^{\lfloor\log_{10}(2a)\rfloor}\cdot a+2a$.

Comment: Doesn't that evaluate to 2a^2 + 2a?

Comment: @alienCY it can also mean concatenation among other things. For example, if $a=3$ and $b=4$, then one might use $\overline{ab}$ to denote $34$.